# Should I comment on non-answer posts after I flagged them?

Tags: support, flagging, review-page

It is a bit unclear to me what happens when I flag a post as 'not an answer'. Obviously a maintainer will look at it, but how is the post shown to the poster?

Basically; should I include a comment explaining what the user did wrong? Or will the flag already show the user an automated message? Or does the moderator post a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I include a comment explaining what the user did wrong?

Please! Yes, that would be great. Be nice, of course.

> will the flag already show the user an automated message?

No, the OP doesn't get notified about a flag on their post.

> does the moderator post a comment?

Usually, if the flagger hasn't done so, yes. There may be times when we don't (we know the same user has been told the same thing a bunch of times and is ignoring it, for example).

Comment: Thanks, I partially assumed there would be some generic notification similar to the 'on hold' or 'closed' description underneath a post, so refrained from adding a comment to prevent adding duplicate information. I will add a comment in the future.